# How to specify external image store location in VueJS 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Normally images in vue are in

```
 <project-root>/src/assets
```

But I need to specify external location for image store such as:

```
/Users/tom/imageStore
```

So that now

```
<img src="images/one.jpg">
```

is mapped to

```
/Users/tom/imageStore/images/one.jpg
```

This will allow production vue app (running from dist folder) to be independent of image store. I can store new images in external store without having to production build vue app everytime new content is stored in imageStore.

Comment: Your images will always need to be in a publicly available folder for them to be displayed, so just link to the location, and make sure you publish them there. If you really need something like this, make a component that wraps the img tag so you can add a prefix in the component, but seriously not sure this is what you need or want.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that for your site to display any images, your images need to end up in the production build. That is, with `npm run build`, the images are copied over to the `dist` folder. That means that webpack in particular needs to know how to find the images. In general I recommend against keeping your images outside your project. Why? Because this interferes with source control software. The images are an integral part of your project, and without it your application looks like it is broken.

If for some reason you still want to approach them with a different path than the one you write in your Vue files, I think you can use a symlink. Symlinks synonimize two paths. If you symlink `<projectRoot>/images` to `/Users/tom/imageStore/images`, it should be able to find your images there. Symlinks like these could also cause security vulnerabilities if used irresponsibly.

If your images are within your project, but you want to approach them with a different path, you can create an alias in your webpack configuration. A webpack alias will resolve paths with a certain name to a different directory. This works just as well for imports in scripts.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would bd, leveraging [devserver proxy](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy) for the `images` route proxying to a local directory served via a simple server like [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve).

As soon as your app requests an image, it will be served from a different folder than `public`.

For production, you could make use of [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) Blocks from nginx, to serve images from another folder than the rest of your app. Or you could perhaps configure nginx to serve from Amazon s3 buckets. Whatever you like.